# angular.js and untappd API, how to send a Get request

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to connect to Untappd API trought angular.js; the API docs says

> Whenever you are making a call to the API, you MUST pass both your Client ID and Client Secret as GET params like below 
>   http://api.untappd.com/v4/method_name?client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET

with angular I have done this simply controller

```
function UntappdController($scope,$http) {
$http.get('http://api.untappd.com/v4/user/badges/jonnyjava?client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX').success(function(data) {
    alert('ok');
 }).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('ko');
});
}
UntappdController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

but it doesn't work. (I get always KO)

So I'have tried tro a RESTful service. In this way

```
angular.module('BadgeServices', ['ngResource']).
factory('Badge', function($resource){
  return $resource('http://api.untappd.com/v4/user/badges/jonnyjava/', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET',params:{client_id: 'XXX', client_secret: 'XXX'}, isArray:true}
  });
});
```

But this doesn't works too...
What I'm doing wrong? I'm new to angular. It looks simple but I'm missing something fundamental...

Comment: **if** API returns JSONP , need to make jsonp request, otherwise need to use a proxy for cross domain request. Not all API's have jsonp output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was a CORS problem. If anyone is interest the solutions is here.
[stackoverflow-Angularjs issue $http.get not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542278/angularjs-issue-http-get-not-working?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

The `error` function is passed these variables: `data, status, headers, config`.  Check their contents - I'm sure the server has some why of specifying what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot it! Here is what I get with the error function..

```
data: status:0 headers:function (name) {
    "use strict";
if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);
if (name) {
  return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
}
    return headersObj;
}config:[object Object]
```

Nothing helpful...