# AngularJS $http.get not displaying data

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, http

My data displays when I call URL from dataSource: but not when I use $http.get. I am passing this data into a dx-chart using a JsonResult from my controller.  Here is code which includes my AngularJS file and MVC View:

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module('customCharts', ['dx']);

$http.get("http://localhost:53640/Home/PostChart").success(function (data) {
    $scope.dataSource = data;
    $scope.renderChart();
})

$scope.renderChart = function () {
    $scope.productSettings = {
        dataSource: $scope.dataSource,
        title: 'Displays Product Costs for items in our Database',
        series: {
            argumentField: "Name",
            valueField: "Cost",
            type: "bar",
            color: '#008B8B'
        },
        commonAxisSettings: {
            visible: true,
            color: 'black',
            width: 2
        },
        argumentAxis: {
            title: 'Items in Product Store Database'
        },
        valueAxis: {
            title: 'Dollor Amount',
            valueFormat: 'currency'
        }
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="customCharts">
    <div ng-controller="ChartController">
        <div dx-chart="productSettings"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No.  My chart just doesn't display any data, but the chart itself is there.  But when I remove the $http.get and just use dataSource: ('URL') my data is populated into the chart.

Comment: @jumpingcode ^^^ see above for reply

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542278/angularjs-issue-http-get-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved this issue.

```
var app = angular.module('customCharts', ['dx']);

app.controller("ChartController", function ($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.productSettings = {
        dataSource: new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
            load: function () {
                var def = $.Deferred();
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:80/Home/PostChart'
                }).success(function (data) {
                    def.resolve(data);
                });
                return def.promise();
            }
        }),
        series: {
            title: 'Displays Product Costs for items in our Database',
            argumentType: String,
            argumentField: "Name",
            valueField: "Cost",
            type: "bar",
            color: '#008B8B'
        },
        commonAxisSettings: {
            visible: true,
            color: 'black',
            width: 2
        },
        argumentAxis: {
            title: 'Items in Product Store Database'
        },
        valueAxis: {
            title: 'Dollor Amount',
            valueFormat: 'currency'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm amazed that DevExpress hasn't accommodated their libraries to interact better with AngularJS.  It seems that they wrap everything up with their classes that take away from two-way binding that AngularJS is known for.

Comment: So what you're saying is basically DevExpress = Poop

Comment: That would be accurate.  :)

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get("http://localhost:53640/Home/PostChart")` will return a promise object, that promise will get resolved when your server controller action returns a data. You should get data first after resolving promise and then render your chart by passing a data.

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('customCharts', ['dx']);

app.controller('ChartController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:53640/Home/PostChart").success(function(data) {
        $scope.dataSource = data;
        $scope.renderChart();
    })

    $scope.renderChart = function() {
        $scope.productSettings = {
            dataSource: $scope.dataSource,
            title: 'Displays Product Costs for items in our Database',
            series: {
                argumentField: "Name",
                valueField: "Cost",
                type: "bar",
                color: '#008B8B'
            },
            commonAxisSettings: {
                visible: true,
                color: 'black',
                width: 2
            },
            argumentAxis: {
                title: 'Items in Product Store Database'
            },
            valueAxis: {
                title: 'Dollor Amount',
                valueFormat: 'currency'
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: No luck with that either my friend.  Now I now longer am displaying my chart OR data...

Comment: These are the console errors when I hit 'F12' Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ChartDesign.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined
angular.js:9101 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ChartController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/ng/areq?p0=ChartController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:78

Comment: at assertArg (angular.js:1346)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1356)
    at angular.js:6636
    at angular.js:6083
    at forEach (angular.js:307)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:6070)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:5536)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:5539)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:5444)
http://localhost:53640/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I added the HTML and .cs code above to my original post if that helps.  I think it has something to do with the way I am passing renderChart to the MVC view

Comment: could you please also provide me a json response content?

Comment: It is just some generic data I put in to test this dx-chart widget...[{"Name":"Learn SQL Server 2014","Cost":34.95},{"Name":"ASUS PC","Cost":499.99},{"Name":"SQL Server 2014","Cost":600.00}]...etc etc

Comment: @Tim  I don't understand why you going for library which is not used by people much? why you don't go for highcharts, angualr-chart, etc,

Comment: lol me either, but Sr. developer asked me to do it this way.  I think because our project is already built using dx-chartjs.js

Comment: I feel like your answer should have worked.  It makes perfect sense, I am still playing with it, but cannot figure out why it will not display dx-chart or Json data.

Comment: Ok, if it's easier for you I can just zip into Dropbox and provide you the link to project folder

Comment: @Tim not able to create working plunkr or fiddle, as it not working here

Comment: Here is project .zip file via Dropbox if you would like to edit: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xkvvljophbb7lp/DashboardExample.zip?dl=0

Comment: project link is above

Comment: @Tim check my answer. It just works. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @Tim where is your answer?

Comment: Not sure if you saw @pankajparkar, but I did post an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two-way binding in order for the chart to update properly. Add this in your dx-chart attribute:

```
    <div dx-chart="{
       ...
       bindingOptions: {
         dataSource: 'dataSource'
       }
    }"></div>
```

where dataSource is an attribute of your scope ($scope.dataSource) that you will update after you perform the $http.get successfully.

Check the documentation [here](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Visualization/Charts/Data_Binding/?version=14_2#Data_Visualization_Charts_Data_Binding_Update_Data_Using_AngularJS)