# AngularJS http get data doesn't match with the data sent out by the server

Tags: json, angularjs, http-headers, request

```
$http.get( 'http://api.com/?id=' ).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) { console.log(data); }
```

The data logged from here onto the browser console shows one of the nested list as empty.
Structure of data being sent out from server:

```
`Server data = 
 {
  status_message : '',
  ourVar: {
      time: '',
      date: '',
      name: '',
      list1: [],
      list2: [],
      group: [
               aList:[
                         {
                           name: '',
                           id: '',
                           ourList: []
                         }
                       ]
             ]
     }
     var2: [
            {},
            {},
            {}
           ]
     var3: [ a:{ 
             a1:[ 
                 {}, 
                 {}, 
                 {}
                ] 
               },
             b:{ 
                b1:[ 
                    {}, 
                    {}, 
                    {}
                   ] 
                },
           ] 
  }
 }`
```

ourList is being shown up as empty while there is data coming from the server. This sounds weird but, it's happening. What's going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your console display anything else?

The problem might have occured due to CORS policy. Try this approach:
[Angularjs issue $http.get not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542278/angularjs-issue-http-get-not-working)

Or maybe you have not specified any GET parameters (in URL) for your request.

Once you provide more information I will update my answer.

Cheers